# Rich Text Field mailto Option

Tags: redactor, richtext

Wondering if there is anything (plugin or otherwise) I can put into my Redactor json file that will generate a mailto option in the insert link dropdown? I can’t seem to find anything on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to do this in Redactor II other than going into Source view and manually entering the `mailto` syntax.